# Cannot set property 'Creating' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I see there are a lot of questions already about "Cannot set property 'Creating' of undefined".

Unfortunately, I can't solve my problems with the other topics.

I recently started to work with Google App Maker and am trying to build a project mangement app. I looked under the hood from the sample "Project Tracker" app from Google.

```
function addTicket(addButton)  {
  var addTicketPage = addButton.root;

  if (!addTicketPage.validate())  {
    return;
  }

  var props = addTicketPage.properties;
  var ticketDs = addTicketPage.datasource;

  props.Creating = true;
  ticketDs.saveChanges({
    success: function() {
      props.Creating = false;

      if (app.currentPage !== app.pages.TicketView) {
        return;
      }

      var newTicket = ticketDs.item;

      newTicket._loadHistory();
      gotoAddTicketPage(newTicket._key, true);
    },
    failure: function(error)  {
      props.Creating = false;
      console.error(error);
    }
  });

  gotoAddTicketPage();
}
```

I looked everywhere in the sample app, but I can't find anything that corresponds to this ".Creating".

What does it do? Do I have to declare it first? Because I already tried this and get the same error.

Thanks in advance.
Adrian

Debugglog:

```
Cannot set property 'Creating' of undefined
at addTicket (TicketErfassen:55:18)
at TicketErstellen.Form1.Form1Footer.Form1SubmitButton.onClick:1:1
```

Comment: `addTicketPage.properties` is probably undefined. Just check in the debugger.

Comment: check **props.Creating = true;** .props is undefined here

Comment: I added the debugg log in my original post.@DenysSéguret

Comment: As far as I see it, props is defined. @NullPointer

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the solution to my problem.

In AppMaker you can set custom properties on pages. I didn't know that.

So I just had to make a custom "Creating" property on the given page.